# How to express a "push for simplicity" when explaining complex topics?

Tags: phrase-requests

Many times, when discussing a complex topic, you are asked to make it simpler so a lay person can understand it and relate to it. However, not everything can be made simple; yet, there is a push to make things simpler (e.g. when you are pitching, talking to a reporter, etc.).

How can I express this push for simplicity, which I don't necessarily agree with?

Comment: Can you provide more context? It is not clear what you are asking for.

Comment: The "KISS principle": Keep it simple, son.

Comment: What about trivialize? Google explains it as 
making (something) seem less important, significant, or complex than it really is.
"the problem was either trivialized or ignored by teachers"

Answer (score 1):

**Dumbing Down**

[wiki](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dumb_down)

> Verb[edit]
>   dumb down (third-person singular simple present dumbs down, present participle dumbing down, simple past and past participle dumbed down) 
>   (idiomatic, transitive) To convey some subject matter in simple terms, avoiding technical or academic language, especially in a way that is considered condescending.
>
> The public won't understand this concept. We need to dumb down our explanation of it.
>   (idiomatic, intransitive) To become simpler in expression or content; to become unacceptably simplistic. 
>   Television has really dumbed down over the past ten years.
>   Synonyms:- 
>   (convey subject matter in simple terms): oversimplify, downplay, simplify, trivialise, vulgarise / vulgarize

Comment: Op asking for name of phenomena, need or demand to simply.

Answer (score 0):

Using [**plain language**](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tcdnstyl-chap?lang=eng&lettr=chapsect13&info0=13):

> The purpose of a plain-language approach in written communication is to convey information easily and unambiguously. It should not be confused with an oversimplified, condescending style. Rather, by choosing straightforward vocabulary and sentence structures and by organizing and presenting your material clearly and logically, you can save the reader time and effort and ensure that your message will be clearly understood.